# Matplotlib tight_layout causing RuntimeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have come across a problem when using `plt.tight_layout()` to try to tidy up a matplotlib graph with multiple subplots.

I have created 6 subplots as an example and would like to tidy up their overlapping text with `tight_layout()` however I get the following RuntimeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 37, in <module>
    fig.tight_layout()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1606, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 334, in get_tight_layout_figure
    raise RuntimeError("")
RuntimeError
```

My code is given here (I am using Python 3.4).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 1000)

fig = plt.figure()


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 3)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 4)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, 7)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, 8)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, 9)

for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I suspected originally that the problem could be from having subplots of different size, however the [tight layout guide](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/tight_layout_guide.html) seems to suggest that this should not be a problem. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: To the downvoters: could you explain why you feel this question should be downvoted? If you feel it could be improved in some way then please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is definitely not a helpful error message, although there's a hint in the if clause that leads to the exception. If you use IPython, you'll get some additional context in the traceback. Here's what I saw when I tried to run your code:

```
    332         div_col, mod_col = divmod(max_ncols, cols)
    333         if (mod_row != 0) or (mod_col != 0):
--> 334             raise RuntimeError("")
```

Although you can use `tight_layout` with subplots of different size, they have to be laid out on a regular grid. If you look closely at the documentation, it's actually using the `plt.subplot2grid` function to set up the plot that's most closely related to what you're trying to do.

So, to get exactly what you want you'll have to lay it out on a 3x6 grid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig = plt.figure()

# Top row
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (0, 0), colspan=6)

# Middle row
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (1, 0), colspan=3)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (1, 3), colspan=3)

# Bottom row
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (2, 0), colspan=2)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (2, 2), colspan=2)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 6), (2, 4), colspan=2)

# Plot a sin wave
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

# Make the grid nice
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

The first argument gives the grid dimensions, the second gives the top left grid position for the subplot, and the `rowspan` and `colspan` arguments say how many points in the grid each subplot should extend over.

Comment: If you use IPython, you'll get more lines of context from each step in the traceback, which helped. I've added this to my answer above.